# Chainlink node operator - reset password

Tags: dashboard, change-password, chainlink

I forgot the password to my chainlink node operator dashboard,

There is no option to reset password on the UI of the dashboard.

how do I reset the password?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have access to the machine itself, you are able to reset the password by following the steps outlined here https://docs.chain.link/docs/miscellaneous/#change-your-api-password.